# Dynamic programming doesn't retrieve all the values that I expect

Tags: c++

Here's the problem that I'm trying to solve:

> Given a value N, if we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S = { S1, S2, .. , Sm} valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? The order of coins doesn’t matter.
>
> For example, for N = 4 and S = {1,2,3}, there are four solutions: {1,1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {2,2}, {1,3}.
>
> So output should be 4. For N = 10 and S = {2, 5, 3, 6}, there are five solutions: {2,2,2,2,2}, {2,2,3,3}, {2,2,6}, {2,3,5} and {5,5}. So the output should be 5.

Here's my solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

std::optional<std::vector<int>> findCoins(int n, int array[], int nrCoins)
{
    if (n == 0) return std::vector<int>();
    if (n < 0) return std::nullopt;

    for (int i = 0; i < nrCoins; i++)
    {
        int x = n - array[i];
        std::optional<std::vector<int>> xRes = findCoins(x, array, nrCoins);
        if (xRes != std::nullopt)
        {
            xRes->push_back(array[i]);
            return xRes;
        }
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}

int main()
{
    int vector[3]{ 1, 2, 3 };
    int nr = 0;
    std::vector<int> coinuri = findCoins(4, vector, 3).value();
    for (int num : coinuri)
    {
        std::cout << num << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For that example, the recursion tree looks like this:

[image: photo]

<sup>it's not the best picture</sup>

But, instead of getting 7 results from my program (because in the tree there are 7 leafs with value = 0), I only get 1 result, and that one is the most left-sided one.

I think that in order to get 7 results instead of 1, I should use a matrix and store each result - that's why my program only returns 1. But, how can I do that using `std::vector`?

Comment: `int vector[3]{ 1, 2, 3 };` -- I would not recommend that you name your variables the same as C++ classes.  All it does is make to make the code confusing to look at.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes - that's a good tip, thanks :)

Comment: *I think that in order ...* -- Also, you don't have to guess what happens.  Use the debugger to confirm what is happening, so that you have a clear idea of what solution would be necessary.

Comment: This program isn't really suitable for dynamic programming, because dynamic programming assumes it doesn't matter which path is used to reach a particular state (and if you make the number of each type of coin used part of the state identifier, then dynamic programming isn't doing you any good anyway).  Better to just use straightforward dynamic recursion.

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand your point. Can you help me store each result as I said though? That's the most important part for me right now, because I kind of understand how the problem should work, but I don't know how to output all the values. As I said, I think I need to store each set of value (when a leaf has the value 0 it means I need to store the path) into a matrix, but I don't know how.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu -- `std::vector<std::vector<int>> allAnswers;...std::vector<int> currentAnswer;...allAnswers.push_back(currentAnswer);`

Comment: *"how many ways"*. it seems you don't have to return `std::vector` at all.

Comment: I considered a little further, and dynamic programming will work if your recursive definition involves *types* of coins and not *number* of coins.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, but I want to do it like that just as an exercise.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've tried to do something like that already, but I didn't figure it out.